# partially reconstruct information of function convoluted with boxcar kernel

Tags: math, signal-processing, analysis, convolution

the function (f) I want to reconstruct partially could look like this:
[image: original function f]

The following properties are known:

- It consists only of alternating plateau (high/low).
- So the first derivation is zero respectively undefined at the edges.

The function was convoluted with a kernel fulfilling the following conditions:

- It is a boxcar function
- Its center is at x=0
- Its integral is 1.

I want to reconstruct only the positions of the edges of the original function (f) from the convolution result (c). So just these positions are of interest to me:
[image: interesting edge positions in f]

If the convolution kernel width (k) is less than the minimum plateau width (b, 40 in the example above) of f, c looks as follows:
[image: boxcar convolution result c with k=31]
(The width of the box car convolution kernel here is k=31.)

In that case it is easy to reconstruct the edge positions:
I look for (possibly broad) extrema, and in between to neighbours [e1_x, e1_y] and [e2_x, e2_y] (one of them is a minimum and one a maximum of course), I search the x0 fulfilling: c(x0) = (e1_y + e2_y) / 2.

The reconstructed edge positions look like that:
[image: successfully reconstructed edge positions]

But if k > b my approach fails:
[image: failing in reconstructing edge positions]
(k=57)

Is there a possibility to calculate the original edge positions in f, if g (and so k) and c are known, also for the k>b cases?

Comment: You might have better luck with this at http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ah, OK. I will post there. Thanks. :)

Comment: It has been solved in the forum acheong suggested: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381470/partially-reconstruct-information-of-function-convoluted-with-boxcar-kernel